# React-Native Pedometer values issue (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, pedometer

I'm using `rn-universal-pedometer` to get steps count and distance data in an app. This is working all great in iOS app. But in Android app there are some issues. If I check live steps and distance and stop the listener, and query back the past data, it shows the same data that I got in live steps and distance for all the given time periods in `queryPedometerDataBetweenDates`. All the values are same and never changes when the time period changes. But this is working perfectly fine in iOS. Is there anything I am missing? I have tried many pedometer libraries. Same issue is there. In some libraries, I got `startDate` and `endDate` as negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used `rn-universal-pedometer` for iOS and `react-native-google-fit` for Android